# Getting unauthorized error after setting the authorization token in the header of retrofit call

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am using retrofit2 with okhttp3. Here I have set my token but still, it shows unauthorized error. It did not go inside the try-catch of the below code.(i.e) the token not get printed)

My approach is to use a single file for retrofit service and it will be used in all other calls.

Here is my code

```
public static Retrofit getClient() {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();
        OkHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        clientBuilder.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ApiConstant.SERVER_API)
                .client(createOkHttpClient())
                .client(clientBuilder.build())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();

        return retrofit;
    }

 private static OkHttpClient createOkHttpClient() {
        final OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

        if (isTokenRequired()) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(Profile.getToken())) {
                String token = Profile.getToken();
                httpClient.addInterceptor(
                        new Interceptor() {
                            @Override
                            public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {

                                Request newRequest = null;
                                try {
                                    System.out.println("token ==" + token);
                                     newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                                            .header("Authorization", "Token " + token)
                                            .build();
                                    System.out.println("newRequest ===" + newRequest);

                                }  catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                return chain.proceed(newRequest);
                            }
                        });
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException("No Token");
            }
        }
        return httpClient.build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the Authorization Header which is [incorrect](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml) (there is no such Authorization type). Token based Authentication is of the format `Bearer <TOKEN>` and not `Token <TOKEN>`

Also check if your Interceptor is actually added, which should work with the correction specified.

Comment: My authorization header is token only.

Comment: Tried it seperately? Also, check if the interceptor is added.

Comment: Separately means, shall i need to add the header interceptor separately. I didn't get you

Comment: You've used two OkHttp Builders, once having the HttpLoggingInterceptor, and another having your Token Interceptor. Check your code in the question, there are two `client()` calls in which the second overrides the first (the one with Logging)

Comment: Yes it overrides. So can you let me know one thing, If I use the HttpLoggingInterceptor then the client call not works as expected. Then how can i make or print the logs

Comment: Shall I need to close every responses when hitting the call. Did you know any thoughts

Comment: HttpLoggingInterceptor should not be the reason for changes in working of a request. Share your current code after the correction in my last comment.

Comment: I have added in the answer section

Comment: Shall I need to close every response when hitting the call. Did you know any thoughts????

Comment: No. Consuming the response implicitly closes it from further use. But I believe we're diverting from your question. If your issue is resolved, you may close this.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after removing the HttpLoggingInterceptor

```
public static Retrofit getClient() {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();
     
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ApiConstant.SERVER_API)
                .client(createOkHttpClient())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();

        return retrofit;
    }

 private static OkHttpClient createOkHttpClient() {
        final OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

        if (isTokenRequired()) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(Profile.getToken())) {
                String token = Profile.getToken();
                httpClient.addInterceptor(
                        new Interceptor() {
                            @Override
                            public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {

                                Request newRequest = null;
                                try {
                                    System.out.println("token ==" + token);
                                     newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                                            .header("Authorization", "Token " + token)
                                            .build();
                                    System.out.println("newRequest ===" + newRequest);

                                }  catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                return chain.proceed(newRequest);
                            }
                        });
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException("No Token");
            }
        }
        return httpClient.build();
    }
```